# Difference between Multiplier and Constant in AutoLayouts

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am currently learning how to create layout constraints programatically. So till now I thought the **Constant** is the value of UIElement's size(like height or width) and **Multiplier** is something we need to get multiplied with the SuperView like

```
titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo : thumbImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier : 0.5)
```

**so according to the above code,**

```
if thumbImageView.width = 40(constant), the width of titleLabel = 20(halved by multiplier)

addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subtitleTextView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: 20))
```

Now in above code, constant is 20, and multiplier is 0, so the resultant will be zero right? But the it is displaying the text view with size 20.

[image: Screen Shot]

So when I change the code with multiplier as 1, and constant as 20. It gets drawn beyond the cell.

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
```

[image: Screen Shot]

**My questions are:**

1.What is the relation and difference between multiplier and constant here? 
 2. I somewhat understood that if two views are mentioned in
    constraints, multiplier can't be zero. Is it correct?
 3. Why the text view is getting dragged along the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto layout constrain is work like mathematic function

```
item1.atribute = Multiplier * item2.atribute  + constant
```

In your Case :
   `titleLabel.width = 0.5 * thumbImageView.width  + 0`

if you do not specify value of Multiplier and  constant then it use default value. Default value for  Multiplier = 1  and constant = 0

Please check auto layout guide of apple for more detail : [AutoLayout Guide of Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

1. Multiplier will be calculated firstly. For example, you make ALabel equal width to BLabel with multiplier 0.5. The Auto Layout will get the width of BLabel and multiply 0.5, and then set the result to ALabel's width.
2. Constant will adjust the result of Step 1. Positive means make it greater while negative smaller.